# How can I view/change/disable the time server in Windows XP, when no "Internet Time" tab?

Tags: windows-xp, ntp

Normally, the "Date and Time Properties" dialog has a third tab "Internet Time" where you can turn on/off the use of a time server, or change where it points.

This tab is missing, and Windows is frequently setting itself to the wrong time, which is very frustrating.

How can I confirm what time server is being used, and then either change it to a working one, or simply disable the time synchronization entirely?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command line tool *w32tm*.  This tools lets you set the time server as well as the parameters surrounding it.  An example, to set the time to use time.windows.com

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com /syncfromflags:ALL
```

Note for most of the parameters you will need to restart the *Windows Time* Service by running (note the spelling)...

```
net stop w32time && net start w32time
```

See full details here: [TechNet - w32tm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx)

Comment: If you use `w32tm ...options... /update` you don't have to manually restart the service with `net stop / start`

Comment: While true, I prefer the two-step approach to address any changes to w32tm configuration I want to make before committing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article.. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307897
Relevant for time service for xp.

Article included here:

> This article describes how to synchronize the time on your computers
>   by using the Windows Time Service.   In Microsoft Windows XP, the
>   Windows Time service automatically synchronizes your computer's
>   internal clock with other clocks in the network. The time source for
>   this synchronization varies, depending on whether the computer is
>   joined to an Active Directory domain or to a workgroup.
>
> When the computers are part of a workgroup, you must manually
>   configure the time synchronization settings. You might identify a
>   computer as a locally reliable time source by configuring the Windows
>   Time service on that computer to use a known accurate time source,
>   either by using special hardware or by using a time source that is
>   available on the Internet. You can configure all other workgroup
>   computers manually to synchronize their time with this local time
>   source.
>
> If the computers belong to an Active Directory domain, the Windows
>   Time service configures itself automatically by using the Windows Time
>   service that is available on domain controllers. The Windows Time
>   service configures a domain controller in its domain as a reliable
>   time source and synchronizes itself periodically with this source. You
>   can modify or overwrite these settings, depending on your specific
>   needs.  How to synchronize the time on a member computer in an Active
>   Directory domain
>   1.Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Accessories, and then click Command Prompt. 
>   2.Type w32tm /resync, and then press ENTER.
>
> How to synchronize an internal time server with an external source
>   1.Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Accessories, and then click Command Prompt. 
>   2.Type the following line, where peerlist is a space-separated list of Domain Name System (DNS) names or IP addresses of the appropriate time
>   sources, and then press ENTER:  w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual
>   /manualpeerlist:peerlist
>
> 3.Type w32tm /config /update, and then press ENTER. Notes•The most common use of this procedure is to synchronize the internal network's
>   authoritative time source with a very precise external time source.
>   However, you can run this procedure on any Windows XP-based computer. 
>   •If the computer cannot reach the servers, the procedure does not
>   succeed and an entry is written to the Event log.  •You can use
>   computers on the Internet to provide accurate time information. For
>   example, use the National Institute of Standards and Technology
>   (NIST), which provides the NIST Network Time service.
>
> How to configure services
>
> How to start, stop, pause, resume, or restart a service Note You must
>   be logged on as an administrator or a member of the Administrators
>   group to complete this procedure. If your computer is connected to a
>   network, network policy settings may also prevent you from completing
>   this procedure. 1.Click Start, click Control Panel, click Performance
>   and Maintenance, click Administrative Tools, and then double-click
>   Services. 
>   2.In the Details pane, click the service.
>   3.On the Action menu, click Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, or Restart. 
>   4.To configure the startup parameters for a service, right-click the service, click Properties, and then type the parameters in the Start
>   parameters box before you click Start. These settings are used only
>   once and are not saved. A backslash character () is treated as an
>   escape character; type two backslashes for each backslash in a
>   parameter.  Notes•If you stop, start, or restart a service, any
>   dependent services are also affected.  •Changing the default service
>   settings might prevent key services from running correctly. Use
>   caution when you change the Startup Type and Log On As settings for
>   services that are configured to start automatically.
>
> How to configure how a service is started Note You must be logged on
>   as an administrator or a member of the Administrators group to
>   complete this procedure. If your computer is connected to a network,
>   network policy settings may also prevent you from completing this
>   procedure. 1.Click Start, click Control Panel, click Performance and
>   Maintenance, click Administrative Tools, and then double-click
>   Services. 
>   2.Right-click the service that you want to configure, and then click Properties. 
>   3.Click the General tab, and then in the Startup type box, click Automatic, Manual, or Disabled. 
>   4.To specify the user account that the service can use to log on, click the Log On tab, and then use one of the following methods: ◦To
>   specify that the service use the LocalSystem account, click Local
>   System account.  ◦To specify that the service use the LocalService
>   account, click This account, and then type NT AUTHORITY\LocalService. 
>   ◦To specify that the service use the NetworkService account, click
>   This account, and then type NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService.  ◦To specify
>   another account, click This account, click Browse, and then specify a
>   user account in the Select User dialog box. When you are finished,
>   click OK.
>
> 5.Type the password for the user account in the Password box and in the Confirm password box, and then click OK.  Notes•Changing the
>   default service settings might prevent key services from running
>   correctly. Use caution when you change the Startup Type and Log On As
>   settings for services that are configured to start automatically. •If
>   you enable or disable a service and you encounter a problem in
>   starting the computer, you might be able to start the computer in Safe
>   mode. You can then change the service configuration or restore the
>   default configuration.  •If you select the Allow service to interact
>   with desktop check box, the service is configured to provide a user
>   interface on a desktop. This feature is available only if you click
>   Local System account and only if the service is configured to interact
>   with the desktop.
>
> Troubleshooting  Clients not synchronized with servers can occur if
>   the Windows Time service has been stopped manually. To resolve this
>   issue, start the Windows Time service.
>
> To start the Windows Time service: 1.Click Start, point to All
>   Programs, point to Accessories, and then click Command Prompt. 
>   2.Type net start w32time, and then press ENTER.